# Android TelephonyManager.getNetworkType() returned constant values in bearer speed order?

Tags: android

TelephonyManager.getNetworkType() returns one of the constant values.

It appears that the constant values have an integer order, by possible bearer link speed.

I know using constant values used in the following manner is generally bad,

however could one use this to determine a basic cutoff for application functionality and have it work between API levels? (in API-v1 there was nothing above 0x03)

```
if( telephonyManager.getNetworkType() > TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE )
{
     return "3G! party on!";
}
else if( telephonyManager.getNetworkType() > TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN )
{
     return "2G, OK. just don't go nuts!";
}
else 
{
     return "No data sorry"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assume they are in order because they are not. For example, LTE is 13 while HSPAP (HSPA+) is 15. Those are not in order. I wrote a "speed ranking" piece of code, which assignes each network type its own speed rank

```
public static int getNetTypeSpeedRank(int t) {

    switch (t) {
        case -1:
            t = -1;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            t = 0;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
            t = 1;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            t = 2;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            t = 3;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            t = 4;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            t = 5;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            t = 6;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            t = 7;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            t = 8;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
            t = 9;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            t = 10;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            t = 11;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            t = 12;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
            t = 13;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
            t = 14;
            break;
        case ContextManager.MDM_NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
            t = 15;
            break;
        default:
            t = 16;
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. The question was posed before many of these network types were added to the android API so it's good to see your code for doing what is ultimately needed. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't count on that behavior.